# Turn off nprogress for some ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using NProgress to display when an AJAX request is running. It works great but I have one AJAX request that I want to run in the background without displaying the progress bar to the user.

I'm binding it to jQuery's `ajaxSend` and `ajaxComplete` events so all the `$.ajax()` calls will display NProgress.

```
$(document).bind("ajaxSend", function() { 
  NProgress.start(); 
}).bind("ajaxComplete", function() { 
  NProgress.done(); 
});
```

The AJAX call I'm making looks like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
  // Setting to not display nprogress here?
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "testurl.aspx",
    data: post,
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function(msg) {
      ;//
    },
    complete: function(msg) {
      ;//
    },
    error: function(msg) {
      ;//
    }
  });
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the global AJAX event handlers for a single request you can set the `global` property to `false`:

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
    global: false, // add this
    type: "POST",
    url: "testurl.aspx",
    data: post,
    cache: false,
    // other properties...
  });
}, 10000);
```

There's a couple of other things to note, though. Firstly `bind()` was deprecated a *long* time ago. You should look to use [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on) to bind event handlers now instead. Also double check the version of jQuery you're using. It should be something v3.x, with jQuery.migrate as well if you need legacy IE support.

Secondly, AJAX polling is an anti-pattern, even when used at a relatively high interval as 10 seconds, as it causes unnecessary load on your server. If this is for a public-facing site and you want to keep the UI and server-side data in close sync, look in to using something like WebSockets instead.